# QuantityArray vs Array of Quantities

Tags: units

If memory and speed are not concerns, is there a reason to use QuantityArray instead of an array of quantities?

Comment: @DanielHuber, it is possible to have something like QuantityArray[RandomInteger[10, {1000, 2}], {"Meters", "Seconds"}], where units are different at the deepest level. This actually works for the n deepest levels. The simplest case is indeed when n = 0, with all entries having the same unit.

Comment: @jose  You are right, I was mistaken. Thanks for the hint. I deleted my note.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think speed and memory are the primary reasons for using a `QuantityArray`.

Another benefit is the formatting, a summary box is a more compact visual representation. At a glance you can see the dimensions of the array, the units, and with one click you can see the min and max values.

Comment: The compact summary box is indeed quite useful. Clicking the Plus sign gives you bounds information, for example.

Comment: Thanks Jose - I updated the response.